# Not calling before fragment is shown

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

I'm showing fragments in viewpager, and each fragment contains data connection.
I don't want to do something, before selected fragment is shown.
How can I do?

I mean, I don't want to initiate fragments when the activity calls oncreate.(because there's data connection, and I don't want it)
I just want to initiate each fragment, when fragment is selected.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    List<Fragment> listFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    listFragments.add(new Fg_1());
    listFragments.add(new Fg_2());
    listFragments.add(new Fg_3());
    listFragments.add(new Fg_4());
    listFragments.add(new Fg_5());
    listFragments.add(new Fg_6());
    a_pagerAdapter = new A_PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), listFragments);
    viewPager.setAdapter(a_pagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating all of your fragments in your activity onCreate, have your viewPager create them when requested, so for a simple example:

in your implementation of A_PagerAdapter, override getCount() and getItem(int) to be something like:

```
public class A_PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
...
  private final static int NUM_PAGES = 6;
  private final Fragment[] listFragment = new Fragment[NUM_PAGES];
...
  public int getCount() {
    return NUM_PAGES;
  }
...
  public Fragment getItem(int index) {
   Fragment itemFragment = null;
   if (listFragment[index] == null) {
    // Hard-coded class factory.. yuck.
    switch(index) {
      case 0:
       itemFragment = new Fg_1();
       break;
      case 1:
       itemFragment = new Fg_2();
       break;
      case 2:
       itemFragment = new Fg_3();
       break;
      case 3:
       itemFragment = new Fg_4();
       break;
      case 4:
       itemFragment = new Fg_5();
       break;
      case 5:
       itemFragment = new Fg_6();
       break;
    }
    // Save this instance in case it is asked for again later..
    listFragment[index] = itemFragment;
   } else {
     // get the fragment we created earlier to avoid re-initializing
     itemFragment = listFragment[index];
   }
  return itemFragment;
 }
 ...
```

This is a fairly simple/horrible implementation.. in reality it sounds more like you need a caching/lazy loading strategy, possibly triggered in the onResume of the fragments in your view pager..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Chats", "Groups", "Contacts","Profile" ,"Settings"};
    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter() {
        super(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return   tabTitles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
```

//            return PageFragment.create(position + 1);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    ChatScreenActivity chatScreenActivity = new ChatScreenActivity();
                    return chatScreenActivity;
                case 1:
                    GroupChatActivity groupChatActivity = new GroupChatActivity();
                    return groupChatActivity;
                case 2:
                    ContactsActivity contactsActivity = new ContactsActivity();
                    return contactsActivity;
                case 3:

```
              ProfileActivity profileActivity= new ProfileActivity();
                return profileActivity;
            case 4:
                SettingActivity settingActivity = new SettingActivity();
                return settingActivity;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }*use this code and do setadapter for your viewpager*
}
```